# Custom Graphql Schema Generation on React using AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I'm making a serverless app on React using aws-amplify, And I want to add Graphql usage in it, but facing some problems.

I want to make a customization to my graphql schema by adding condition such that when svc_level is diploma or high school then it won't ask for course_title and course_name until unless svc_level is selected as college or university. Below is my graphql code:

```
type AnswersPageData @model {
  id: ID!
  svc_title: String!
  svc_tag: String!
  svc_level: String!
  question: [Question]!
  solution: String!
}

type Question {
  header: [QHeader]
  info: [QInfo]
  body: [QBody]
}

type QHeader { 
  title: String!
  referenceStyle: String
  pagesNum: Int
  status: Boolean!
  rating: Int
}

type QInfo {
  course_code: String!
  course_title: String!
  university: String
  country: String
}

type QBody {
  Content: String!
  tags: [String]!

}
```